# .htaccess redirect subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow the users to type

```
xyz.example.com
```

in order to reach

```
test.php?id=xyz
```

What code should I use to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your example.com domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the host is anything.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
#send all requests to test.php
RewriteRule .* test.php?id=%1 [L]
```